# Remove a button with javascript

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to remove a button after it is clicked (the button was created in javascript) and from a different post it said this code would work, but in my console i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
at HTMLUnknownElement.<anonymous> (RBrOJeLwYgRM:335)
```

Why? Help!
Code:

Code that is supposedly going to remove elements:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My code which activates the remove function:

```
else if (PaintBrush.crashWith(Finish)) {
      PaintBrush.y = 50;
      var button = document.createElement("button2");
button.innerHTML = "Level 2";
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);
      GameArena.clear();
      GameArena.stop();
      button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  startGame2();
        document.getElementById("button-2").remove();
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `document.createElement("button2")` button? Are you trying to create an element with a `button2` tag or a `button` with an id of `button2`?

Comment: `Why?`  Because you're trying to access `.remove` of `null`, just like the console error says.  where are you calling `.remove()`, what are you calling `.remove()` on, and why do you think it might be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes

```
PaintBrush.y = 50;
var button = document.createElement("button"); //  remove the "2"
button.innerHTML = "Level 2";
button.id = "button-2";  // add the id to the button
document.body.appendChild(button); // append to body
GameArena.clear();
GameArena.stop();
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  startGame2();
  document.getElementById("button-2").remove();
});
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! Really helpful, i had named it button2 because i had some css to position it, but creating a css id called button-2 and styling that works aswell. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped, If you want to keep the "button2" class, you cand add it also, just use:
button.className = "button2";